# how to implement php native / pure php custom function to cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, barcode, barcode-printing

Here is a php barcode generator php [barcode generator](https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator).

How to implement this function in cakephp?

Can I use Component, Helper or anything else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: T_T I have tried with that plugin, but not support barcode type 128, is there any plugin for cakephp that support 128 type barcode ?

Comment: for cakephp where should I take that file ?

Comment: Corrected grammar.

Comment: ok, I got it, Just put that file in webroot, then call it in my view to show barcode